# Discord oauth2 - Send message as User

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, oauth, discord

I am looking to create an application in which I connect with oauth2 to my discord account, in order to send in all the channels where I am, a message, with my own account (not as a BOT)

Only I don't see any options in the scope https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes to do it. Even if I put them all in, I will be able to read messages at best, but not write them.

How could I do this? Thank you !

Comment: you can't connect a OAuth2 to your discord account, those are for discord applications and bots, what your looking for is a selfbot (authomated user account) which is against their [tos](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-). If you want to make a selfbot you would need access to your discord account and define that in your code by your discord token for example and log into it

Comment: And if I understand correctly, Discord is against that, and if they detect the use of a self-bot, we get banned?

Comment: yes discord is against that and you may risk getting your account deleted :/